# I need suggestions about making Learning Management System

Tags: architecture, software-design

I want to know if I want to build a simple Learning Management System, that works for both mobile and web. The system should contains virtual classrooms and etc. What are technologies that are suitable to implement this type of system in a short time and without needing a big team.

Fun fact, My team use the following technology:

1. HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript
2. React.js
3. Node.js
4. MongoDB
5. Flutter
6. Firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how big a solution you want to build and maintain, versus, how how quickly you want to get to market and how feature rich you want it to be.

Building an LMS from scratch is a huge project.  I don't think it's likely you can build a good one with a small team and in a short time unless you use lots of pre-built components/systems... in which case your solution will require you to do more integration and configuration than anything else.

It's been a while since I looked, but there are lots of vendors and SaaS / PaaS providers that do LMS related systems.  Some will do systems that handle the learning development and delivery, others will handle the student management side, some will do everything.

Comment: Thanks, I think we need to search for existing components to build this project then 